# Como podría consumir esta api en php, es posible?

Tags: php, api, curl

Quiero aprender a consumir la api https://www.iphunter.info/es/docs y saber de donde vienen las visitas.

Solo he podido imprimir los datos por `cmd` y el comando `curl` y el ejemplo que da la pagina, pero no encuentro como integrarlo a mi web.

Al agregar el código a mi web

```
 '<php
$ip = '148.56.53.217'; //-- IP a consultar
$apiKey = 'MI CLAVE DE ACCESO';

$headers = [
    'X-Key: '.$apiKey,
];
$ch = curl_init("https://www.iphunter.info:8082/v1/ip/".$ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), 1);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);`

e imprimir
con print_r($output);

?>'
```

no me arroja nada, y http_status solo me arroja cero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema con las comillas en tu código, nunca has cerrado la comilla después de apikey, además abres una comilla ANTES de <php con lo cual casi todo tu código es un "comentario"
Aquí tienes el código funcionando:

```
<?php
    $ip = '148.56.53.217'; //-- IP a consultar
    $apiKey = 'KEY-AQUI';

    $headers = [
        'X-Key: '.$apiKey,
    ];
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.iphunter.info:8082/v1/ip/".$ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), 1);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($output);
```

Y el resultado:
[image: Resultado]

Comment: En estos casos, avisamos del problema en un comentario, y cerramos la pregunta como error tipografico...

Comment: Ahm, lo siento. No vi esa regla en ningún lado. Además, el error estaba en el código, no su pregunta, no? Lo siento si pregunto cosas raras, me gustaría ayudar a la gente pero también seguir las reglas :)

Comment: No hay ningun problema!!! solo te lo aclaraba porque en general esta clase de errores no ayuda a nadie mas y por eso las cerramos!!! gracias por la ayuda!!! si tenes alguna duda, siempre podes preguntar en el [chat]

Comment: Entiendo, tiene sentido. Gracias por comentármelo, y por el chat, no lo conocía

Comment: Lo siento no me permitia poner el codigo, soy nuevo aquí y fue mi primer pregunta, pero gracias intentaré con lo que comentan

Comment: @Benito-B lo he puesto tal cual, y asi es como tenia el codigo, el problema es que no me arroja los datos que te arroja a ti y no encuentro el problema

Comment: Estás seguro de que tienes una API key válida y bien puesta, @AntonioFernandez ?
Porque si lo tienes así, debería de funcionar a no ser que sea tu propia máquina la que está impidiendo la conexión

Comment: Hola Benito-B si la clave es correcta puedo solicitar los datos solo cmd con la clave, pero he puesto el codigo en php con la clave y sale en blanco
$apiKey = 'KEY-AQUI' en ese espacio es donde pongo la clave, incluso subi el codigo a un hosting y el resultado es el mismo en blanco.

Comment: Benito-B mi pc es la que esta bloqueando la conexion, he analizado el codigo online y funciona, ahora el problema es que no se como hacer que funcione en mi pc local y el mi hosting

Comment: Te recomiendo que para eso abras otra pregunta con esa duda, así podremos ayudarte todos y si alguien tiene el mismo problema encontrará la solución facilmente también :)

Comment: pude resolverlo les dejo lo que hice por si alguien tiene el mismo problema...
al intentar retornar el status me daba cero, lo que investigando decía que era un error al conectarse con el servidor. Para saber cual era el problema después de curl_exec agregue esta linea print curl_error($ch); 
lo que me devolvió  esta respuesta "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
y en esta respuesta pude resolver el problema [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate]